# Different style per citation?

Tags: biblatex

I am using Biblatex and try to mimic Harvard referencing. Therefore, I have set the style to `authoryear` in the brackets when setting the package up. I set it to that style because that is how you would cite a source with an author. However, when I try to cite a website without an author, and only an editor/publisher, I want to cite the source as (Title Year) and not (Editor/Author Year). How is it possible to change the citation depending on certain criteria so that you can satisfy a certain referencing standard (such as Harvard)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. It would be helpful if you composed a fully compilable [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) including `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages that sets up the problem. While solving problems can be fun, setting them up is not. Then, those trying to help can simply cut and paste your MWE and get started on solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike other styles such as APA style<sup>(https://www.apastyle.org/manual, `biblatex` implementation [`biblatex-apa`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa))</sup> and Chicago style<sup>(https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/home.html, `biblatex` implementation [`biblatex-chicago`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-chicago) and more recently [`windycity`](https://ctan.org/pkg/windycity))</sup> the term *Harvard style* does not refer to a well-defined and unique citation and bibliography style. Instead Harvard style is used to refer to a broad class of author-year citations. Many schools, universities, institutes and professors have their own interpretation of what "Harvard style" should mean exactly.

The `biblatex` standard style [`authoryear`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/50-style-authoryear-biber.pdf) or its variants [`authoryear-ibid`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/51-style-authoryear-ibid-biber.pdf), [`authoryear-comp`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/52-style-authoryear-comp-biber.pdf), [`authoryear-icomp`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/examples/53-style-authoryear-icomp-biber.pdf) are usually a good starting point for Harvard style.

Indeed those styles already give you a  *title year* citation if there is no author or editor.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@online{ics,
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {2019},
  url     = {https://example.edu/impcs.pdf},
  urldate = {2019-03-11},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\begin{document}
Lorem \autocite{sigfridsson}
ipsum \autocite{ics}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Lorem (Sigfridsson and Ryde 1998) ipsum (On the Importance of the Civil Service 2019)]

Comment: Thanks man! But the thing is that I want to provide an editor to the online source in the bibliography (not an author though). And since an editor is not an author, I would still like to use the title rather than the Editor when citing the source - is this possible?

Comment: @step `useditor=false` as entry option? (I.e. add `options = {useeditor=false}` to the `.bib` entry.) Without a proper example (at best a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864, https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864) that's mostly guessing, though.

Comment: You are a true savior! Exactly the options that I wanted.